# 1and1 .htaccess directives: explanation needed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, custom-error-pages

I have no experience with modifying .htaccess file.
I'm trying to add custom error pages to my website, and I got the following template from the hosting provider (1and1). I know how to add the pages, but I would like to understand line by line what the code is doing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /errordocument.html
ErrorDocument 400 /errordocument.html
RemoveType x-mapp-php4 .html
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with line one:

`RewriteEngine On` - quite a simple one, it says it in the name, it enables the rewrite engine to allow us to do many things. (I wont go into detail on what all these things are)

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` basically checks for anything that isn't a file or a directory, if these two conditions are met, it will move on to the `RewriteRule` if not, then nothing past this will be run.

`RewriteRule (.*) /errordocument.html` - This is basically telling the server that if the above conditions are met, to redirect to the error page named `errordocument.html`. (This coincides with your above conditions being met of course).

`ErrorDocument 400 /errordocument.html` - Simply put, this just tells the server that if a 400 error is received, to then display the `errordocument.html` page.

Finally `RemoveType x-mapp-php4 .html` - This is basically telling your Apache server to remove any extensions that are `.html` from the end of your URLs.

For more in-depth information into each of these and how extensively they can be used, take a look at the Documentation for Apache by clicking [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/)

I hope this helps you to understand what is going on a bit better.

Comment: Thanks, Lag! With your help I fixed my .htaccess :)